# Update properties of a model

Tags: javascript, node.js, model

I am trying to implement a feature where I can press on a button to delete some properties of my model.

My Model is:

Request:
   status
   shopper

I am using an event based structure:

This is the front end

```
 a.requests-deny(href='#', data-id=request.id) Deny request
```

and this is my backend

```
var Request = require('../../models/Request');
var ShopperRequests = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.shoppers-requests',

  events: {
    'click .requests-deny'  : 'requestDeny'
  },

  requestDeny: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(e.currentTarget);
    var requestId = target.data('id');

    console.log(requestId);

    Request.findById(requestId, function(err, request) {
      console.log(request);
      if (err) {
          return console.log('oh no! error', err);
      } else {
          request.status = 'pending';
          request.shopper = '';
          request.save(function(err) { // <-- save it back to the database
            if (err) {
              console.log('oh no! could not be saved in db', err);
            } else {
              console.log(request);
            }
          });
        }
    }); 
  },
```

Looking at the console in the browser I see that first of all I can't use "require" because "it's not defined"

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined(anonymous function) @ shopper-f28ac0daf1d6a206b3172e4b9c670dd4.js:1
```

I was thinking of taking the requestId and just updating the values in the database but apparently this is not working. 
Any idea if this could work or how else I could implement it?

Comment: looks like it's backbone.js

Comment: I'm using node.js but this is now backbone.js

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading the `RequireJs` library in your backend. Thats why you are getting `require is not defined`.

If you are using Node, add it like this:

```
npm install requirejs
```

Or else, download it from [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html), and add it to your project with a script tag.

Comment: I am loading Require.js in the backend

Comment: Could you share the code where you load the library please?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly..I am loading the library though: var Request = require('../../models/Request');

Comment: No, you are trying to "require" the `Request` library there. You need to include the Require.js file in your backend.

Comment: How would I do that? I though requesting it is enough..I have it saved in the model.

Comment: the problem is not requesting the model `Request`. The problem is the library that you use to "request" js files.